# Conditional filtering in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write a stored proc for a search page. The search page allows the user to choose "Any" for some filters and each filter maps to a column in my DB.

What is the best way to approach this in my stored proc:

(1) Should I go with dynamic SQL (sp_executesql) and construct the query based on the filters chosen? Would this have any negative impact on caching of the execution plan?

(2) Should I translate "Any" to all possible values and use the same in a static query?

(3) Should I store the results in a temporary table using the mandatory filters and then apply the optional filters (that support ANY option) one-by-one on these results?

(4) Any other approach that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Not a complete answer so I'll post as a comment, but do **NOT** do `2` - the query engine will still check that field when it doesn't need to (i.e. if you specify a list of all values for a table in an `IN` list, it'll still check every row)

Comment: Required reading on this topic; http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing how the user chooses the filter, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE (FILTER_FOR_COL_A IS NULL OR COL_A = FILTER_FOR_COL_A) 
AND   (FILTER_FOR_COL_B IS NULL OR COL_B = FILTER_FOR_COL_B)
```

`FILTER_FOR_COL_A` is the filter value for column `COL_A`. If the user has choosen `ANY`, `FILTER_FOR_COL_A` will be `NULL`. Obviously, if `COL_A` can be `NULL` and the user should be able to specify this as a filter, `NULL` isn't the best way to represent the `ANY` filter. You would need to think of another value or a second parameter for this. Additionally, this approach won't work if the user can specify multiple filter values for one column.

Comment: Guarenteed to give you poor execution plans. Erland Sommarskog's blog that Alex linked to covers some of the gory details. Not the SQL2008 way of getting your example to work well by specifying statement RECOMPILE was broken and so removed in SP1+.